# Android POST to server always returns false response code

Tags: java, android, http, post, http-post

I am having trouble passing a POST request to a web server from an Android application. I have created a page that accepts a POST parameter "data" with a string value, and I have checked that it works with the Google Chrome Postman extension. However, when I attempt to send data from the Android application, I always get a false HTTP response code, as if data was not passed to the server at all.

```
private void sendDataToServer(final String uri, final String data) {
    Log.d("Debug", "MainActivity -> sendDataToServer (start)");
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            try {
                // Set up connection
                Log.d("Debug", uri);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL(uri).openConnection()));
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Write
                OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                Log.d("Debug", data);
                writer.write("data=" + data);
                writer.close();

                // Read
                int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

                Log.d("Debug", String.valueOf(responseCode));

                if (responseCode == 200) {
                    Log.d("Debug", "Message sending: Success!");
                    // TODO: Do something with the results
                } else {
                    Log.d("Debug", "Message sending: Failure...");
                }

                urlConnection.disconnect();

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                Log.d("Debug", e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("Debug", e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    };
    t.start();
    Log.d("Debug", "MainActivity -> sendDataToServer (end)");
}
```

The web server's code:

```
$postData = $_POST['data'];//file_get_contents("php://input");

if ($postData) {

  $connection = connectToDB();

  $array = json_decode($postData);

  foreach ($array as $element) {
    addMessage($connection, $element->timestamp, $element->sender, $element->message);
  }

  disconnectFromDB($connection);

  http_response_code(200);

} else {

  http_response_code(400);

}
```

What could I do to fix this behaviour?
I am running Android Lollipop.

Comment: What is the response code you get?

Comment: @abdulrahmank The exact response code doesn't matter. I currently just return a certain HTTP response code (different from 200) from the server if it doesn't get an appropriate string as a POST variable. However, I have checked with the Postman extension that a string of the format that is passed in the application should be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Since you use `"Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` so I suggest you refer to my sample code as the following:

```
    private class POSTRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            String address = "http://...";
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
            String requestBody;
            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("key1", "value1");
            params.put("key2", "value2");            

            // encode parameters
            Iterator entries = params.entrySet().iterator();
            while (entries.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) entries.next();
                builder.appendQueryParameter(entry.getKey().toString(), entry.getValue().toString());
                entries.remove();
            }
            requestBody = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

            try {
                URL url = new URL(address);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "utf-8"));
                writer.write(requestBody);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                outputStream.close();

                InputStream inputStream;
                // get stream
                if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() < HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST) {
                    inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                } else {
                    inputStream = urlConnection.getErrorStream();
                }
                // parse stream
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String temp, response = "";
                while ((temp = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += temp;
                }
                // do something...                

                return response;
            } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                return e.toString();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "POST\n" + result);
        }
    }
```

---

UPDATE:

I have just tested and got 200 response code with the following:

Android (I hard-code the data):

```
...
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("data","[{\"timestamp\":\"2015-12-26 07:02:00.557\", \"sender\":\"58576402\", \"message\":\"4\"}]");
...
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$postData = file_get_contents("php://input"); // $_POST['data'];//file_get_contents("php://input");
if ($postData) { 
  //$array = json_decode($postData);
  http_response_code(200);
} else {
  http_response_code(400);
}
?>
```

Comment: I still have the same problem. I get the response code I specified for an erroneous result (400) and data isn't passed to the web server (I know because otherwise, data rows are added to the web server database). When I use Postman and pass the same data, it is passed correctly.
I also get the same problem when using raw content type.

Comment: http://imgur.com/hlqQUtY
The response code is 200 and data rows were added to the database on the web server. I am using the same data as in the Android application.

Comment: When you debug your app, does requestBody look like the following or not `data=%5B%7B%22timestamp%22%3A%222015-12-26%22%7D%5D...`?

Comment: It does, after encoding the string - but the response code is still not 200, independent of encoding it.

Comment: If your server url is published in Internet, please post it so that I can check more. If not, IMO, you should debug it to see more details

Comment: It's not public. I do not do much in the web application. I posted the code in the first post. What kind of debugging would you suggest?

Comment: If you use my code, try Log.i("requestBody", requestBody); then post it here to check

Comment: `data=%5B%7B%22timestamp%22%3A%222015-12-26%2007%3A02%3A00.557%22%2C%20%22sender%22%3A%2258576402%22%2C%20%22message%22%3A%224%22%7D%5D`

Comment: I outputted the $_POST variable to a file in the web server. If sent from the Postman extension, it contained the correct information, however, if sent from the Android application, $_POST was empty.

Comment: Pls try `JSONObject json = new JSONObject();                
                json.put("data", "your_json_data");               
                String requestBody = json.toString();` and `urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");`

Comment: `$_POST` (and even `php://input`) is still empty in the web application - no data is passed from the Android application.

Comment: Try `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>` or `var_dump($_POST)` in web app to see if it has any info?

Comment: It has info when using Postman, but not when using the Android app.

Comment: I have just tried, it works. Pls wait, I am going to update my answer soon

Comment: I replace `file_get_contents("php://input");` by `$_POST['data'];`, it's 200 OK too :)

Comment: I somewhy still get 400. I hard-coded the data just as you did, and changed the server file to what your's is.

Comment: My web app environment: Apache24 (Windows), PHP 5.6.5, the php page has only simple content as in my answer :)

Comment: Mine does, too. I'm using PHP 5.5.

Comment: I think you can try a new PHP file with only the following content `<?php
  http_response_code(200);
?>` and check if android client received 200 or not, then replace 200 with 304, 400, 404... to test

Comment: Yes, it received 200 with only that.
This seems hopeless.

Comment: Try check php.ini `http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.always-populate-raw-post-data`. If still not working, IMO, you can try with another server (perhaps with PHP newer version)